# Use browsers language settings to set language (rlmp_language_detection)

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.2.x, language-detection

I try to automaticly set the language in my typo3 6.2 One-Tree Page.

To my setup, I use RealURL to add the langauge to the URL, I use the default `L`parameter. I DON'T use ISO codes for the languages, but I use static_info_tables to set the ISO Code. For the language switch I try to use the extention `rlmp_language_detection` but it does not work.

My language config (typo3name, Official ISO Code - selected with static_info_tables, ID - used for `L`parameter)

- default, -, 0
- en-jp, en, 1
- en-us, en, 2
- jp-jp, ja, 3

My Typoscript for the plugin:

```
plugin.tx_rlmplanguagedetection_pi1 {
   useOneTreeMethod = 1
   defaultLang = en
}
```

My Typoscript for langauges:

```
config {
sys_language_uid = 0
language = en
locale_all = en-eu
}

[globalVar = GP:L = 1]
config {
sys_language_uid = 1
language = en
locale_all = en-us
}
[global]

[globalVar = GP:L = 2]
config {
sys_language_uid = 2
language = en
locale_all = en-jp
}
[global]

[globalVar = GP:L = 3]
config {
sys_language_uid = 3
language = jp
locale_all = jp-jp
}
[global]
```

To test it I set my first langauge to japanese and when I request the rootpage this is in my request-header:

```
Accept-Language:ja,de-DE;q=0.8,de;q=0.6,en-US;q=0.4,en;q=0.2
```

http://mybrowserinfo.com/ say:

```
Language:Japanese
System Language:Not detectable with this browser
User Language:de
```

But no `L` Parameter is set at all, so I get the default language.

Comment: you mean that when you use navigation you no `l` parameter ?

Comment: @Fixus I call the page without a `L` parameter. (When I add a `L`-Parameter I get the right language - but the idea is that this works automaticly)

Comment: when you set the `L` parameter is it rendered in navigation ? I mean can you navigate on page with correct language ?

Comment: @Fixus sorry for late answer. Yes the translation works. Just the detection/redirection not.

Answer (score 4):

I've had same problems:
How i made it works step by step:

**1 Step:** 
install `static_info_tables` be careful it should be in DB utf-8 charsetin latin1 (in my case) don't work

**2 Step:** 
istall `rlmp_language_detection`

**3 Step:** 
check if on you server installed `php-geoip` php module, if not install Ext: `ml_geoip` or any way install it.

**4 Step**
[image: include static templates]
include static templates in your TS template

**5 Step**

### [image][image]

Pls don't forget to choose ISO code of toy lang in base line pages tree

**6 Step**
TS settings - add this after all lang configuration

```
plugin.tx_rlmplanguagedetection_pi1 {
   # this mean that you hav ejust one tree pages for all lang, for multi trees look manual
   useOneTreeMethod = 1 

   #important - this your website sys_language default
   defaultLang = ru 

   # use -1 when you wont to test redirect, after change to 0
   cookieLifetime = -1 

   # you defind which method will be used for redirect browser or ip, better testing just with one
   testOrder = browser,ip

  # we can config aliases like "code = lang1, lang2"
  languageAliases >
  languageAliases {
    ua = uk,en
    en = en
    ru = ru,en
  }

  #we can country codes dependencies "country code = lang"
  countryCodeToLanguageCode >
  countryCodeToLanguageCode {
    ua = uk
    us = en
    gb = en
    nz = en
    au = en
    ie = en
    ca = en
    by = ru
  }

  #this just limit input params array
  limitToLanguages = ru,uk,en 

}

# ok just after all we include ext to page, on ts begining you shoud to have "page = PAGE" just check
page.1007 = < plugin.tx_rlmplanguagedetection_pi1
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest using .htaccess to redirect the browser acceptance language. This saves you loading up the whole TYPO3 instance just to do a redirect.

Depending on weather you use realurl it would look something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^en-us [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /en-us/ [L,R=307]

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^ja [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /jp/ [L,R=307]

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^en-gb [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /en-eu/ [L,R=307]
```

I don't know how to target en-jp though.

On our websites we use the 307 as status code, so the browser will always look for the initial page (in case the structure changes), also it doesn't affect SEO.

Comment: thanks for the work around. Looks like I will do it like this now. Any idea how I could do a default redirect? Like when the first language in Accept-Language does not fix any of the rules?

Comment: There can be a problem with this solution as it redirects me to a localized page even if I chose the default language given the default language front page resides at /.